# Unable to insert figure using graphicx

Tags: graphics, floats

Following is the command I am putting in, but Latex gives me an error in the line describing the path of the image. 
Is there another way I should rather be defining my image path?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height = 3in]{/Users/kusha/Desktop/msc_dissertation/graphs/kden_2011.jpg}
\caption{Kernel density curves of male and female wages in 2011}
\label{fig:kden_2011}    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex` or with something else?

Comment: *What does the error say?* **(1)** Try a absolute path including the letter of the drive: `C:\Users\manu\picture.jpg` for example. **(2)** Alternatively, place the picture in a folder that is in the same folder as your tex file and use a relative path: `PictureFolder/picture.jpg` for example.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That is the absolute path mac-style

Comment: @samcarter Thanks. I didn't know that :).

Comment: Try to rename your image without using `_` and place it on your desktop

Comment: @samcarter No, I am not using pdflatex or anything else. I'll try renaming without _ though. Thanks!

Comment: @KushaVerma If you rename it, also place it in a place without `_` in the path, i.e. not under `msc_dissertation`

Comment: @KushaVerma If you are not using pdflatex or anything else, how do you compile? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @samcarter Clearly it is not the *correct* absolute path, otherwise `\includegraphics` would have worked! The OP doesn't say he/she is running on a Mac. Storing the images in a folder that is "close to" the TeX files in some sense is a good idea in any case, and using a relative path is then shorter. If you ever need to send the source files to another user, using absolute path names is a very *bad* idea.

Comment: your image is in `jpg` format, which is supported by `pdflatex` but not with `latex`.

Comment: @samcarter I tried using it without the _ and it works now, thanks! 
The image quality is a bit poor though. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: "The image quality is a bit poor though. Is there anything I can do about it?" Make a better quality image? Seriously, how do you expect us to answer that question when we cant access either the image file or your compiled document?

Comment: @alephzero I am using a mac, and that was the correct absolute path. Seems like there was an issue with the use of _

Comment: @KushaVerma jpeg is a bad choice if you want to show a graph or similar. Which software did you produce it with? Can this software export to something else, i.e. a vector graphic format such as pdf? If not even png would be better then jpeg

Comment: @alephzero It was just a question from a person who is new to latex. I am sorry if you found it offensive.

Comment: @KushaVerma As for the problem with the `_` you have some possibilities: either use relative paths or use `\usepackage{griffle}`

Comment: @samcarter It is a Stata graph that I have saved in jpg format. Yes, I can definitely try and see if saving as pdf works better. Thank you

Comment: If `mcs_dissertation` is your latex project foler then may be a `\graphicspath{ {graphs/} }` under `\usepackage{graphicx}` would possibly do your job without more changes (except changing the name of file in includegraphics to the filename instead of the path -and fixing the  `_` to... Sorry didn't noticed the second `_`- )

Comment: @KushaVerma There is a typo in my previous comment, it should be `grffile` - sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

The underscores in the path and in the filename are problematic. Some suggestions:

- rename the dissertation folder and your image without `_`, spaces or any other special letters
- the problem with the dissertation folder name can be circumvented by using relative paths (`\includegraphics[height = 3in]{./graphs/kden-2011}`) or, as suggested by [koleygr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388350/unable-to-insert-figure-using-graphicx#comment963102_388350) setting a graphic path (`\graphicspath{ {graphs/} }` in your preamble and then just `\includegraphics[height = 3in]{kden-2011}`) [please notice that I changed the filename to `kden-2011`]
- using the `grffile` package.

---

Some other comments:

- I suggest not using `[H]`, this will severely handicap latex to do it's job in placing the floats and producing a nice output, try with `[htbp]`
- No need to add a file extension, `\includegraphics{kden_2011}` is fine and if there are different versions of the same image, automatically the best suitable format is choosen
- scaling the image with `height = 3in` is absolutely correct, but personally I find it easier to scale it relative to the document, i.e. `0.5\textwidth` will give an image half the available width etc. - it makes it easier to find the desired scaling and will adapt your images in case you change the document layout.